# Point of smallest height on an algebraic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $C$ be an algebraic curve of genus $g \geq 2$ defined over a number field $K$, and we suppose that $C(K) \ne \emptyset$ ($C$ may very well be defined over a proper subfield of $K$, but perhaps failing to have rational points over subfields). Then using the Abel-Jacobi map we can embed $C$ into its Jacobian $\text{Jac}(C)$, which is endowed with a Neron-Tate height $\hat{h}$. Applying this height to the image of $C$ in $\text{Jac}(C)$ we then obtain a height on $C$ itself.

Bogomolov's conjecture, proved by Emmanuel Ullmo and Shou-Wu Zhang in 1998, asserts that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that the set

$$\displaystyle \{x \in C(\overline{K}) : \hat{h}(x) < \epsilon \}$$

is finite. It thus follows that there exists an algebraic point on $C$ of *minimal* height.

My question is this: let $S(C)$ be the set of real numbers $r$ such that $\# \{x \in C(\overline{K}) : \hat{h}(x) \leq r\} = \infty$ and let $h_{\text{min}}(C) = \inf S(C)$. Can $h_{\text{min}}(C)$ be determined by other invariants of the curve, such as the Faltings height?

Comment: I don't think that this is quite what you want to ask. If you use $x_0\in C(K)$ to embed $C$ into $J$, then the image of $x_0$ is the identity element of $J$, so if you vary over all $x\in C(K)$, the minimal  value of $\hat h(x)$ is $0$, since you can take $x=x_0$. So maybe it would be better to define $h_\min(C)$ to the the infimum over all $\epsilon>0$ such that $$\#\{x\in C(\bar K) ; \hat h(x) <\epsilon\}=\infty.$$

Comment: @JoeSilverman Thanks, I will make that change

Comment: A priori this number depends on the choice of a rational point. Or maybe you want to take the minimum over all rational points?

Comment: The Abel-Jacobi map is defined by a choice of a degree one $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor $D_0$ defined over $K$. If you want a truly canonical choice, a standard convention is to take $D_0 = \frac{1}{2g-2} K_C = \frac{1}{2g-2}\Omega_C^1$ (indeed this was the convention in Ullmo's paper; for the other cases had been covered anyway by previous papers). Otherwise the invariant clearly depends on the choice of $D_0$, and it will be asymptotic to just the height of $D_0$ if the latter is taken to approach infinity.

Comment: So let me take the canonical choice $D_0=\frac{1}{2g-2}K_C$. The invariant $h_{\min}$ is known as the essential minimum of the curve (arithmetic surface); it is a special case of Zhang's successive minima of an arithmetic variety. It is a subtle invariant whose exact value is not known for any curve, but (by Zhang's theorem on successive minima) it does lie between the canonical "Arakelov $\omega^2$" quantities denoted $\frac{1}{4g-4}(\omega,\omega)_{\mathrm{Ar}}$ and $\frac{1}{2g-2}(\omega,\omega)_{\mathrm{Ar}}$ in Ullmo's paper, and so it is comparable with that canonical height invariant.

Comment: Since you mention the Faltings height, yes, for a fixed $g$
it can now be proved that the latter invariant is also locked between two positive multiples (depending only on g) of the Faltings height of the curve. The easy upper bound of $12h_{\mathrm{Fal}}(C)+O_g(1)$ follows classically by the arithmetic Noether formula (and the $O_g(1)$ can be made fully explicit as well).

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov You should put that material into an answer and delete the comments.